# https servlet call and weblogic configuration

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

We are writing a servlet code which will be restful https client posting request to a different server where restful webservice is exposed. The servlet client will be hosted in weblogic 12c server.  Since it is a https one way ssl call , what configurations do i need do in weblogic to enable TLS 1.2 so that my servlet can use https protocol to communicate to the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enabling SSL on weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020295/enabling-ssl-on-weblogic)

Answer (score 1):

If the https on the hosted web service is signed with a trusted CA, the client does not have to do any additional configurations.

If the certificate is self signed you will have to import the certificate to your weblogic's trust store (which is usually the cacerts in your jre/lib folder of the jdk running your weblogic